# JSON to SQL table, auto assign column names

Tags: sql, json, parsing

I have these JSON files which I need to transform into tables in SQL. I managed to parse the rows but I type the column names manually. Is there a way to get them from the "columns" array?

```
INSERT INTO testdb.dbo.ezjson (jfile)
VALUES('{
  "table": {
     "columns": {
      "col1": "ID",
      "col2": "Name"
    },
    "rows": [
      {
        "col1": 1234,
        "col2": "ABCD"
      },
      {
        "col1": 5678,
        "col2": "EFGH"
      },
      {
        "col1": 9012,
        "col2": "IJKL"
      }
    ]
  }
}');

SELECT 
temp.ID, 
temp.Name 
FROM testdb.dbo.ezjson
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(jfile,'$.table.rows')
WITH(
ID NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.col1',
Name NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.col2'
)AS temp
```

| ID | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | ABCD |
| 5678 | EFGH |
| 9012 | IJKL |